# A proper way to split a partition and move directory

Tags: linux, lvm, partition

Currently, I have Ubuntu 12.04 set up with the following partitions:

```
500G disk with LVM
  80GB root
  4GB swap_1
```

I want to move the folder `/opt` to a new LV, for example:

```
500G disk with LVM
  root (80GB)
  swap_1 (4GB)
  lv_opt (200GB)
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to single user mode to be on the safe side - `telinit 1`
2. Create `opt_lv`
3. Format `opt_lv`
4. Mount `opt_lv` on /mnt
5. Copy and retain all attributes (archive move) `cp -a /opt/* /mnt/*`
6. `umount /mnt`
7. `rm -rf /opt/*`
8. Add fstab entry to mount `opv_lv` on /opt
9. `mount /opt`
10. Go back to multiuser - `telinit 3`
11. Done!

Answer (score 2):

If everything in `/opt` is static, which is probably should be, just copy everything to the new partition with `rsync` or `dd` or whatever and then modify `/etc/fstab` to mount the new partition as `/opt` and reboot.

If it's not static content, you can either stop anything that would be writing to it before the copy, or just boot into single-user mode and do the copy to be safe.